# In Qt 4.8.5, the differences between setPaused(false) and resume() after setPaused(true) in QTimeLine

Tags: c++, qt

In the source of qtimeline.cpp, **setPaused(false)** and **resume()** are almost the same as followd:

```
d->timerId = startTimer(d->updateInterval);
d->startTime = d->currentTime;
d->timer.start();
d->setState(Running);
```

In docs, **setPaused(false)** resumes the timeline and continues where it left, but **resume()** resumes the timeline from the current time.
Can anyone explain the different result from the "same" code?
I read the solved topic http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/28076 "QTimeLine setPaused doesn’t pause the time line correctly". But I still cannot find out the reason.

Comment: On my tests, I found that **resume()** after **setPaused(true)** the timeline resumed from the point where paused, but **setPaused(false)** after **setPaused(true)** the timeline almost never stopped and "_jumped_" a big step when first **valueChanged()** signal emitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### THE INTENTION

The intended difference between `resume ()` and `setPaused (false)` are the following:

- `resume` will unconditionally change the state of `QTimeLine` to `Running`, no matter what the previous *state* of it was, whereas;
- `setPaused(false)` will not do anything unless the state is currently `Paused`.

---

#### THE SOURCE CODE

The implementation of `setPaused` have a check to see that the state is indeed `Paused` before running the code you have in your question, which is why "the same code" yields different results.

The below is the entire body of `resume`, but only a minor part of the definition of `setPaused` (after the bug fix).

```
d->timerId = startTimer(d->updateInterval);
d->startTime = d->currentTime;
d->timer.start();
d->setState(Running);
```

The previous (buggy) implementation of `setPaused (x)` had the following in the branch for `state == Paused`, and `x == false`:

```
d->timerId = startTimer(d->updateInterval);
d->setState(Running);
```

---

#### WHERE CAN I FIND MORE DETAILS?

The bug fix you are talking about can be inspected in detail under the following links:

- [**Change Ib9b2c5a0: Fixed bug in QTimeLine::setPaused(false)**](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#change,50723)

  - [Change Ib9b2c5a0: src/corelib/tools/qtimeline.cpp](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#patch,sidebyside,50723,2,src/corelib/tools/qtimeline.cpp)

Comment: Does it mean that both `resume()` and `setPaused(false)` will get the same result after `setPaused(true)`, if fixed the bug?

Comment: @sfz if the state prior to `setPaused(true)` is `Running`, yes.